# How to replace HTML nodes using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML file, in which, all

```
<div class="replace-me">
</div>
```

must be replaced with

```
<video src='my_video.mov'></video>
```

The code is:

```
doc.css("div.replace-me").each do |div|
  div.replace "<video src='my_video.mov'></video>"
end
```

It's simple, but, unfortunately, it does't work for me. Nokogiri crashes with the following error:

```
undefined method `children' for nil:NilClass
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2/lib/nokogiri/html/document_fragment.rb:16:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:424:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:424:in `fragment'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:776:in `coerce'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:331:in `replace'
```

Replacing with a `div` works:

```
doc.css("div.replace-me").each do |div|
  div.replace "<div>Test</div>"
end
```

Is this a Nokogiri bug, or did I do something wrong?

The same issue occurs with `add_child`, `inner_html` and other setters for this purpose.

Comment: Be careful thinking you found a bug, especially if you have multiple things that you tried that failed. http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm368 explains.

Answer (score 0):

I will quote my comment from your previous question:

> This happens because of HTML strictness *(HTML has a predefined set of elements)*. Replace Nokogiri::HTML( self.content ) with Nokogiri::XML( self.content ) and do not forget to add a DOCTYPE declaration manually later.

Comment: OK. Let's move to this post :)
It seems to work with replacement. But another problem - when i try to save the modified document's part back to self.content, i get only those parts, that have replaced the old ones. But another elements, that were somewhere around, and were not modified (in self.content) - are gone...

Comment: Very strange. I'm trying to understand why. Could you show your source HTML before any replacements?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the log, the part you chose with Nokogiri turns nil.

Try it this way:

```
doc.css(".replace-me").each do |div|
 div.replace "<video src='my_video.mov'></video>"
end
```

Or you may need to specify which element you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate the problem. Granted, the question is old, but this works:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="replace-me">
</div>
EOT

It could have been a Ruby 1.8 issue, an issue with that version of Nokogiri, or something was wrong in your libXML... it's hard to say given the information in the question.

doc.at('div.replace-me').replace("<video src='my_video.mov'></video>")
doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
#    "<html><body>\n" +
#    "<video src=\"my_video.mov\"></video>\n" +
#    "</body></html>\n"
```